# Updating global GHC/i snapshot in Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm quite new to whole Haskell ecosystem and TBH most of the time learning Haskell I've spent using [Haskell For Mac](http://haskellformac.com). Right now I'm trying to tackle projects manually using [The Haskell Tool Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) as everyone encourages this way of using Haskell.

Everything is pretty straightforward when it comes to using stack in Project's directory, I call `stack setup` and I'm ready to go with the resolver version generated or specified in `stack.yaml` (which usually is the latest version).

My concerns start when I want to use `stack ghci` outside of the project, because it uses `resolver` specified in `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`. Of course I can manually change it to the `resolver` version I want, but what'd make me happy is if it can automatically update to the latest `resolver` when I call `stack upgrade` or something like this?

Continuing with this *upgrade*, can I somehow get rid of the old versions? Because size of `~/stack/` is easily getting *too big*. Let's say I want to achieve something like `stack resolver cleanup` and It'll only leave the latest version. I've seen some suggestions to remove whole `.stack` directory from time to time as a way of cleaning up, but this is rather *hardcore way*, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such command currently. So you can do `rm -rf ~/.stack` periodically if you change your `lts` often. There's an open issue about adding cleaning command that you want with discussion of its design: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/133

But nobody implemented it yet.

Comment: All in all, you have to face everything by yourself, right?

Comment: @cojoj Well, in reality you don't need to switch `lts` often. There should be reasons for this, like you really need bugfixes. Though I agree that having some features like automatically bump-up your global `lts` and clean all garbage would be really nice! But you should consider that `stack` is very young tool comparing to build tools for other languages and comparing amount of effort, dependent on community and ecosystem size, put into it's development.

Comment: I'm not expecting super awesome features out of the box. Having to handle everything manually gives you a clear vision of what you have to do in order to accomplish something, but in that case Stack's documentation lacks some really important entries.

And regarding amount of LTS'... I'm a new player and I already have 4 of them locally! Also, size of my `.stack` is already over 6 gigs...

Comment: @cojoj You just probably shouldn't install a lot of `lts`'. Try to stick to some one. I can expect huge number of locally installed packages when you're experimenting with different libraries.